# Eclipse CDT & TM/RSE

Tags: eclipse-cdt

how can eclipse cdt manage and build remote file with TM/RSE??
There is an example of usage of project that use Eclipse CDT from windows and source and compiler in Linux?

TNX

Comment: Just added some information on the remote build part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Target Management](http://www.ddj.com/embedded/193402474) has long wanted integrated RSE (Remote Systems Explorer) with CDT (C/C++ Development Tooling).
A first bug was opened in 2004 ([bug 65471](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=65471)), and a first crude implementation was proposed in 2006 ([bug 137839](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=137839)).
In 2009, a [proposal to move the RSE "`RemoteCDTLaunch`" feature into CDT](http://markmail.org/message/phrcz3ansvcuzgju#query:cdt%20tm%20rse%20remote%20launch+page:1+mid:oyex57lpp4g5fqvm+state:results) was added.

Right now, the official source of information for using RSE with CDT would be this [Wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/TM_and_RSE_FAQ#How_can_I_do_Remote_Debugging_with_CDT.3F).
Extract:

> There is two very different kinds of setup for remote debugging:
>
> 1. Have the Debugger run on the remote system, and
> 2. Have the Debugger run on the local system, as a cross debugger, with some kind of thin agent on the remote.
>
> The first, "**remote debugging**" case, can be addressed with CDT alone:
>   typically, compilation will happen on the remote host, and all tools need to be available remotely including the debugger.
>   An NFS or Samba mount can be used to make the remote sources visible locally for static analysis and editing.
>   The make command is changed into "`ssh remotehost make -C remoteDir`" and the debug command is changed into "`ssh remotehost gdb`". See [bug 30094](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=30094#c13) comment 13 for more info.
>
> For the second, "**cross debugging**" case, there are multiple options but they all have one prerequisite in common: you **need a cross toolchain installed locally**.
>   That is, your compiler runs locally (e.g. on Windows) and produces output that the remote (e.g. Linux) system can execute.
>   Similarly, your debugger runs locally (e.g. `gdbppc`) and is capable of debugging the remote system.
>   Such a cross toolchain is available from commercial vendors, or you can build one yourself. See [Wikipedia:Cross-compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-compilation) for a starting point.

---

Regarding the Remote build, however, things are less clear:

- some manual process is possible (see [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg16217.html)), but with issue to integrate that with the Problem view.

> We are using "Make Targets" View where "targets" are set up to compile remotely using `ssh`. Seems to be more convinient then to use Build Configuration option.

- the official approach is [Adding Remote Build and Remote File System Support to CDT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/designs/remote/cdt), written in 2006 and which may have been integrated to CDT by now.
  Hopefully, that can be used as a first illustration for what you are looking for.

Comment: Tnx for quick reply, you have mentioned remote debug but remote build??
Any help is appreciate.

Comment: I am looking for remote Bulding yet only, not even thinking about the debugging. I have istalled RSE but i can not find the option or way to build remotely? Did you find a way by now? or pointer? Thanks

Comment: @Denis: I didn't investigate further at the time.